# Content of iframe (ionic app) doesn't scroll on Internet Explorer using touch

Tags: html, iframe, touch, internet-explorer-11, ionic-framework

I'm working on a couple of ionic apps that are communicating with each other. In order to demo them I run them side by side on a webpage embedded in iframes.

When displaying that webpage in Chrome it works just fine. However when showing it in IE on a touchscreen I can't scroll vertically inside those iframes. I debugged it a little bit and it seems that touch events that have vertical movements just don't get passed into the ionic app, whereas horizontal swipes and taps get passed down just fine. It seems like the vertical scrolling of the entire webpage absorbs those events without passing them down.

Has anyone encountered an issue like this before and can tell me if there is a way to fix this?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/2) might be related, though it's actually about ios, it seemed some of the links from there may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks. You pointed me in the right direction. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Captn_Hammer for pointing me in the right direction. The fix is similar on IE. All I had to do was add this to the body of the webpage:

style="-ms-touch-action: none;"